# Xamarin - The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly on visual studio

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, compiler-errors, .net-5

I'm getting this error each time I try to build my Xamarin project on Android emulator. I have vs2019.

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: No se puede encontrar el ensamblado 'Mono.Cecil, Version=0.10.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=50cebf1cceb9d05e'.

Server stack trace: 
   en System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
   en System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
   en System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   en System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
   en System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)
   en System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   en System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   en System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   en System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)
   en System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodReturnMessage.FixupForNewAppDomain()
   en System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage reqMsg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   en System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   en System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   en Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   en Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   en Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() AppCrijoya  C:\Users\usuario\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets 119
```

It says it can't find the "Mono.Cecil" assembly.

How do I fix this? Please help.

Comment: Does this problem happen to every Android APP?Have  you tried to recreate a new emulator？

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT  Yes and this happens to every Android app. My project works on one pc but not another.

Comment: Does the simulator start normally? And you can try to repair your visual studio first.  For more, check [Repair Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT No, the emulator can't even start. I'll try and repair visual studio but I already uninstalled and installed it.

Comment: You can try to delete the emulator and try to create a new one, then try again.